# DataGridComboboxColumn Binding with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, observablecollection, datagridcomboboxcolumn

My little project looks now quite different. Now I have `ObservableCollection OC1` with data which I want to bind with whole `DatagridTextBoxColumns` (via *Binding Path*) and `ObservableCollection OC2` where I store cases for `DatagridComboboxColumn` (as `ItemsSourceBinding`). `SelectedItem` property in `DatagridComboboxColumn` is one value from `OC1` (and it is one of `OC2` cases ofc). 
Binding on `DatagridTextBoxColumns` is ok.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DGoc1" x:Uid="DGoc1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          AlternationCount="2" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,5,0,0" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
  <DataGrid.Columns>

    <!-- This works fine -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=id}" Header="ID" 
                        Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>

    <!-- Dow to bind this properly?? -->
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding OC2}" 
                            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=valueFromOc1}"
                            Header="OC2Cases" Width="Auto"/>
```

C#(**Updated**):

```
public class ClasswithSomeData
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string valueFromOc1 { get; set; }
}
public partial class DGCBC : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> OC2 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ClasswithSomeData> OC1 { get; set;}

    private void tabPanel1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadDG();
    }

public void LoadDG()
    {
    OC2 = new ObservableCollection<string>(someCases);

    OC1 = new ObservableCollection<ClasswithSomeData> { };
    OC1.Add(someData1);
    OC1.Add(someData2);
    OC1.Add(someData3);
    DGoc1.ItemsSource = OC1;
```

How to bind this `DatagridComboboxColumn` properly? Please help with some example.

Answer (score 1):

your observablecollections are declared as fields:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> OC2;
public ObservableCollection<ClasswithSomeData> OC1;
```

they should be Properties:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> OC2 {get;set;}
public ObservableCollection<ClasswithSomeData> {get;set;}
```

Do not forget INotifyPropertyChanged! =)

Comment: Updated. I will add `INotifyPropertyChanged` when this binding will works.

Comment: @werasquez your code doesn't work **precisely** because you did not `INotifyPropertyChanged`!! and you're doing this in the `Loaded` event which is AFTER all bindings have been evaluated, that's why you're not seeing these changes in the UI

Comment: Ok. My mistake. I read a lot of examples with `INotifyPropertyChanged` used but no one is similar as my. I know how it works but I have no idea how to implement it into my code. If you know that, please help.